# Vue dynamic import components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

By default I must declare the components which to use in `components` prop. I want to get the component names in Ajax request, inject the components while the app running and show them, NOT in `components` prop when app startup.

In official document, dynamic component section shows how to switch component while running and async component section shows how to load component in async request when app startup. Both of them can't resolve my question.

Comment: _"Both of them can't resolve my question"_ <- why not?

Comment: @Phil I still need to declare the components in `components` prop, so I must know the components which I need to load when app startup. I want to get the informations about component names in a running time. The components are different by different end users, I cant load all components because they are so many.

Comment: When using `<component>`, you don't need to declare the components upfront in the `components` object *unless* you are binding `is` to a string (the component name), you can bind `is` directly to the component object.

Comment: @DecadeMoon You are right. Thank you. How can I use single file component in this case?

Comment: Did you see the example shown in the [Async Components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components) documentation that specifically says _"One recommended approach is to use async components together with [**Webpack’s code-splitting feature**](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/)"_?

Comment: @Phil I have read it. For lazy loading I need to use magic comments to specific component when build the App. I want to get the component list and import them while app running. The lists will de different.

Comment: What are magic comments?

Comment: @Phil Thank you for your answer. I resolved my question by using `is` with components. About magic comment [here](https://medium.com/faceyspacey/how-to-use-webpacks-new-magic-comment-feature-with-react-universal-component-ssr-a38fd3e296a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my question by using `is` with directive. The component declared in an object, and async request the component via Ajax as a javascript piece. And parse it in `new function(...)`.

The main codes, NOT TESTED.

```
let rawComp="{...}" // Your vue component declaration js object via ajax
let rawHTML="<div>...</div>"//Also your component HTML template
let rawCompWrapper=`return ${rawComp}`
let comp = (new Function(rawCompWrapper))()
comp.template = rawHTML
comp.foo=bar//Other tasks for parsing your component
```

```
<div :is="comp" v-bind="{your:'propertyValues'}"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, how do you async request the component using Ajax and how did you parse it? can you provide the sample code?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually i posted a question few months back https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53406350/vue-import-vue-components-dynamically , but nothing seems to be worked. In my case the problem is, if i deploy in the tomcat, the dynamic import component is not working.

Comment: So i went ahead with importing all the components at once and use it across.

Comment: @Sam I think there are some mistakes with webpack configuration or it's version. [Webpack code splitting doc](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/)