# Dynamic import of Vue JS component: handle "not found" error

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

In my VueJS app I need to load customization components which add functionalities to a main component. These customization components can be inexistant if there is no customization for a specific client.

I was thinking of using async components with import() function like so:

```js
<template>
  <component :is="Component"></component>
</template>

<script>

import { defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue';
import ViewCommon from './ViewCommon.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    ViewCommon,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      Component: null,
    }
  },
  async created() {

    let compPath = "";

    const compPath = "./mods/" + specificApp.name + "/ViewMod.vue";

    this.Component = defineAsyncComponent({
      loader: () => import(compPath),
      errorComponent: ViewCommon,
      timeout: 3000
    })

  },
}
</script>
```

It works well, except that it throws an error in the console if the customization component does not exist. In dev mode, with Vite :
`Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html"...`
In production, I get a 404 in console.

But I want to avoid errors since I know it can happen and have a fallback component.

I also tried replacing the `defineAsyncComponent` function by only using `import()` and handling errors, but is still throwing the same error:

```js
import(compPath).then(
  (mod) => {
    console.log("success")
    this.Component = mod.default()

  },
  (error) => {
    console.log("error", error)
    this.Component = "ViewCommon"
  }
)
```

Is it possible to catch this error? Or do I have to create empty components for clients without customization?

Answer (score 0):

OK I found an answer to my own question!

My mistake was that I was not following the rules of using variables in dynamic imports with Rollup (on which Vite is relying): https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/dynamic-import-vars#limitations

I should not have written:

```js
const compPath = "./mods/" + specificApp.name + "/ViewMod.vue";
import(compPath).then(...)
```

But:

```js
import(`./mods/${specificApp.name}/ViewMod.vue`).then(
  (mod) => {
    console.log("success")
    this.Component = mod.default()

  },
  (error) => {
    console.log("error", error)
    this.Component = "ViewCommon"
  }
);
```

In this last snippet, the error is properly catched.

If I use a variable (`compPath` here) to describe the full path to the file to import, Vite cannot analyse it and it led to this unwanted behaviour.

It should also be possible to make it work with `defineAsyncComponent` by tuning the loader function so that it catches the error and returns a Promise without it, but I finally did not have the need for this.

Comment: This still gives me an 404 error though...?