# Can we catch or suppress the 404 error when async dynamically loading and falling back? (Vue 3)

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

In Vue 3. Trying to dynamically load a component, and fallback to a default if the component doesn't exist.

```js
    const MyList = defineAsyncComponent({
        loader: () => import(`/src/components/${customList}/MyList.vue`).catch(
            () => import('@/components/default/MyList.vue'),
        ),
    })
```

Though this works quite well, it still returns a 404 error when falling back. Wonder if that could be caught to be completely error free.

A related question for non-async import (but still seems to give a 404): [Dynamic import of Vue JS component: handle "not found" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76015820/dynamic-import-of-vue-js-component-handle-not-found-error)